# Android: how to take over message loop of Activity, like GetMessage/PostMessage in Win32?

Tags: android, android-activity, modal-dialog, message-queue

My original goal is to build my own modal dialog. At some point, I have to run an inner loop, which would do really close to what GetMessage/PostMessage do in Win32, if you got Win32 experience then you are quite familiar with this. **The inner loop will block current workflow but still process events**. The pseudo code would be like,

```
private void doModal() {

    doSth();

    // start loop and process events
    while (!isQuit) {
        Message msg = nextMessage();

        // process all wanted msgs, and simply discard all unexpected msgs
        if (isWantedMsg) {
            sendToTarget(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

I've looked into source code, Looper.loop(), which was,

```
public static final void loop() {
    Looper me = myLooper();
    MessageQueue queue = me.mQueue;
    while (true) {
        Message msg = queue.next(); // might block
        if (msg != null) {
            if (msg.target == null) {
                // No target is a magic identifier for the quit message.
                return;
            }
            msg.target.dispatchMessage(msg);
            msg.recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I'd like to write such a loop, then I'm able to receive all msgs and process or drop them accordingly. Unfortunately, MessageQueue belongs to package android.os, I have no privilege to access most of its interfaces. Activity.dispatchTouchEvent is just a handler, not my case.

How could I do? Thanks.

==========================SOLUTION=====================================
I solved it by reflection, I exactly copied source of Looper.loop(), see below,

```
private void startModal() {
    Class clsMsgQueue = null;
    Method nextMethod = null;
    Class clsMsg = null;

    mQuitModal = false;

    MessageQueue queue = Looper.myQueue();
    clsMsgQueue = queue.getClass();
    try {
        nextMethod = clsMsgQueue.getDeclaredMethod("next", new Class[]{});
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    nextMethod.setAccessible(true);

    while (!mQuitModal) {

            Message msg = null;
            try {
                msg = (Message)nextMethod.invoke(queue, new Object[]{});
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (msg != null) {
                clsMsg = msg.getClass();
                Field targetFiled = null;
                try {
                    targetFiled = clsMsg.getDeclaredField("target");
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                targetFiled.setAccessible(true);

                Handler target = null;
                try {
                    target = (Handler) targetFiled.get(msg);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (target == null) {
                    // No target is a magic identifier for the quit message.
                    mQuitModal = true;
                }

                target.dispatchMessage(msg);

                msg.recycle();
            }
        }
    }
```

When dialog was dismissed, mQuitModal was set to true either.

If don't care much about performance issue, it worked.

Comment: Simply put, no professional developer should use this code.

Comment: I am building a debugger for Android and needed to process UI events while paused on the UI Thread (for breakpoints). This code is exactly what I needed. However, I should point out that msg.recycle will not work, you need to call `recycleUnchecked`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, Android deliberately does not support nested event loops like this.  You just will have to structure your code a different way -- for dialogs you will typically start the dialog, return to the event loop, and implement callbacks to handle the result from it.

Comment: Your solution is BROKEN.  Anyone who writes an app using that can expect their app to break.  And we won't try to make it work.